# "Group by" troubles with subquerys

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to do agrupations to show stats, to show income vs expenses by month (the table have date and amount fields). I do this many times in Oracle, with this query:

```sql
select X.ANIO, X.MES, (select sum(INGRESOS) from X)
from (
  select 
    YEAR(fecha) as ANIO, 
    MONTH(fecha) AS MES,
    format(sum(monto), 2) AS INGRESOS, 
    0 EGRESOS
  from in_out 
  where id_user = 0 
  and monto > 0 
  group by YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha) 

  union

  select 
    YEAR(fecha) as ANIO, 
    MONTH(fecha) AS MES,
    0,
    format(sum(monto), 2)
  from in_out 
  where id_user = 0 
  and monto < 0 
  group by YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha)
) X
group by X.ANIO, X.MES
order by 1 desc, 2 desc;
```

The subquery (X table) got the expected result, but the top query don't.

This query works (but take more time)

```sql
select 
  YEAR(X.fecha) as ANIO, 
  MONTH(X.fecha) AS MES,
  (
    select format(sum(monto),2) 
    from in_out 
    where id_user=0 
    and monto > 0 
    and date_format(fecha,'%Y%m') = date_format(X.fecha,'%Y%m')
  ) AS INGRESOS,
  (
    select format(sum(monto),2) 
    from in_out 
    where id_user=0 
    and monto < 0 
    and date_format(fecha,'%Y%m') = date_format(X.fecha,'%Y%m')
  ) AS EGRESOS,
  (
    select format(sum(monto),2) 
    from in_out 
    where id_user=0 
    and date_format(fecha,'%Y%m') = date_format(X.fecha,'%Y%m')
  ) AS DELTA
from in_out X
group by YEAR(X.fecha), MONTH(X.fecha)
order by 1 desc, 2 desc;
```

My doubt is why the 1st query doesn't work.

Comment: The Virtualtable X does not exist when this is(select sum(INGRESOS) from X) is executed so returns null. - What are you trying to do here?

Comment: IN fact in oracle you get ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should also give you what you're looking for (`ingresos / egresos`, per month):

```sql
select 
  YEAR(fecha) as ANIO,
  MONTH(fecha) as MES,
  format(sum(CASE WHEN monto > 0 THEN monto END), 2) as INGRESOS, -- Sum of ingresos 
  format(sum(CASE WHEN monto < 0 THEN monto END), 2) as EGRESOS -- Sum of egresos
from in_out
where id_user = 0
group by YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha)
order by 1 desc, 2 desc
;
```

As to why the outer part of your original query doesn't work, one thing that comes to mind is with your scalar sub-query: `(select sum(INGRESOS) from X)`.  I think it will just return a constant value, which is the sum of all the `ingresos` without respect to groups.  If you see the same value repeated for all months, then this is probably why.

Your original query uses the same `GROUP BY` in multiple levels.  You can eliminate this with the query I included above.

Comment: Whilst this answer will provide the correct solution the question is 'My doubt is why the 1st query doesn't work.'

Answer (score 0):

The Virtualtable X does not exist when this is(select sum(INGRESOS) from X) is executed so returns null.

You seem to want ingresos by year and month so

```
drop table if exists in_out;
create table in_out
(fecha date,monto int, id_user int);

insert into in_out values
('2019-01-01',10,0),
('2019-01-01',-20,0),
('2019-02-01',100,0),
('2019-02-01',-20,0);


select X.ANIO, X.MES, sum(INGRESOS)
from(
select YEAR(fecha) as ANIO, MONTH(fecha) AS MES,format(sum(monto),2) AS INGRESOS, 0 EGRESOS
from in_out where id_user=0 and monto > 0 group by YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha) 
union
select YEAR(fecha) as ANIO, MONTH(fecha) AS MES,0,format(sum(monto),2)
from in_out where id_user=0 and monto < 0 group by YEAR(fecha), MONTH(fecha)
) X
group by X.ANIO,X.MES
order by 1 desc, 2 desc;

+------+------+---------------+
| ANIO | MES  | sum(INGRESOS) |
+------+------+---------------+
| 2019 |    2 |           100 |
| 2019 |    1 |            10 |
+------+------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

Comment: I also tried that way, but didn't work, it bring a bad sum.